# How to push data between routes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-resolver

Assume I am given an `item-list` array in route `/items/`. The item-list.component.html looks something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    ....
  <a [routerLink]="'/items/' + item.id">View Item</a>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is push the `item` object from the `item-list` array to the next page (or route) `/items/:item-id.`

Currently, the way I have it set up is with 2 resolvers, one for each route:
1. GET items-list
2. GET item by id

I realize that there is an unnecessary API call between these routes as the item object I need is already in the array. I plan to refactor the resolver call the API if the item doesn't exist (due to page refresh or direct link)

How would I approach this?

Note: In Ionic3 this could be done like this: `navCtrl.push('ItemPage', {item: item});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service. You can't pass data to routes, other than simple values.

```
export class FirstComponent {
   constructor(private someService: SomeService){}

   someMethod(item) {
     this.someService.currentItem = item;
   }
}

export class SomeService {
  currentItem: any;
}

export class SecondComponent {
   constructor(private someService: SomeService){}

   someMethod() {
    // now you have the item
    this.currentItem.....
    }
}
```

Instead of routerLinking to a route, use the method to redirect and add the item to the service:

so instead of

```
<a routerLink
```

do:

```
*ngFor="let item of items"
<button (click)="route(item)"

myMethod(item) {
  this.someService.currentItem = item;
  this.router.navigate('/route....')
}
```

syntax is not exact; it's just an example

Answer (score 1):

> Note: In Ionic3 this could be done like this: navCtrl.push('ItemPage',
>   {item: item});

You can do the same thing with **[router](https://angular.io/guide/router)**:

```
this.router.navigate(['./item-page', {item: item}]);
```

Then in your next page you add this to `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params);
    });
  }
```

Comment: you cannot pass an entire object like that, it will not work, it will just pass it as query params, rather than the actual object.